# Android How to transfer data between activities without moving to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent

How can i transfer data between two activities, **without** actually move to that activity? The scenario is as follows:

`Activity` A is a splash screen. While the splash screen is showing, some data is being generated in the background of type `ArrayList`. After This data is loaded, i need to start `Activity` B (lets say a Login screen) and just before that i need to transfer the data to `Activity` C. I know i can use `PutExtras` for transferring data, but wont this run the target `Activity` instead only sending the data?

Thanks

The full flow of the app is as follows:

`Activity` A (splash screen) --> `Activity` B (Login screen) --> `Activity` D (some user interface and buttons) --> `Activity` C (the activity which should be able to load the data generated in the splash screen upon certain `Button` press).

Comment: You might use `SharedPreferences`. Though it might not be a good way. It will actually help with Usrname and Password scenario.

Comment: What is `Activity C` purpose? Have you considered making it a `Service` instead? Activities are supposed to be visible.

Comment: Handlers and sending messages between them is a way of handling a task such as this.  Basically using callbacks between Activities when another accomplishes a specific task.

Comment: I used `SharedPreferences` for the user name and pass scenario. `Activity` C should present the data BUT ONLY when certain button is pressed. `Activity` C should be user friendly and load instantly, therefore the "heavy lifting" is done while the splash screen is showing.

Comment: how is activity C started? can you pass the data from activity A to B to C?

Comment: @AlexTal you should store data in database and then load it in Activity C.

Comment: @John Boker please look at the main post, i have added the full flow of the `Activities`.
@Sharj could you please be more specific?

Answer (score 2):

I think You don't fully understand life cycle of Activity and application.

Rule of thumb, there is always just one activity, (it is the worst scenario when each activity has to be recreated when You go back to it) the one visible at the moment. You can't do things like start activity but don't show it yet or anything like this.

If You have expensive task to do like downloading data do it in AsyncTask

- if this task has to be start and finish when You enter and leave Activity A use [fragments](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html)
- if it has to finish once You start whether Activity A is still existing or it was already destroyed use [services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Places You can store this loaded data so it may be easily accessed later form any Activity is [database with help of Loaders](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html)(loader is optional but really nice) or [SharedPreferences.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data to an activity that is running and not start a new instance of that activity you just need to set flags on your intent. For example:

```
Intent i = new Intent()
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

will not re-launch an activity if it is already running at the top of the stack. If all you want to do is get data to Activity C which is running without starting it again you could try this or one of the other flags. There's a bunch of them. Just look look through [the list](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP) and see if one fits your needs.